# What's the meaning of "The wind had been knocked out of me"?

Tags: meaning

Could you please explain  meaning of the phrase generally and meaning of "wind" in this case.

Full text:

My back struck iron: the trailer’s wall. My feet snapped over my head and
I continued my graceless plunge to the ground. The first fall was seven or
eight feet, the second perhaps ten. I was relieved to taste dirt.
I lay on my back for perhaps fifteen seconds before the engine growled to
silence and I heard Dad’s heavy step.
“What happened?” he said, kneeling next to me.
“I fell out,” I wheezed. **The wind had been knocked out of me**, and there
was a powerful throbbing in my back, as if I’d been cut in two.

Comment: This is [easily google-able](https://www.google.com/search?q=meaning+of+wind+knocked+out+of+someone). I understand that you may have not known this was an idiomatic expression, but you should at least share what research you **did** do, so that we know you at least made an earnest effort before asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If somebody hits you or you have a bad fall, the air is sometimes forced out of your lungs. When this happens, we say "... [knocked the wind out of me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getting_the_wind_knocked_out_of_you)..." or "... [winded](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/winded) me ...".

Note that this is not to be confused with the expression "[take/knock the wind out of someone's sails](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take_the_wind_out_of_someone%27s_sails)", which means to discourage somebody.

Comment: I don't understand the phrase *My feet snapped over my head*. Would you mind explaining it? Thank you very much!

Comment: @dan: it doesn't have any specific meaning. Just replace **snapped** with **went**. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3):

**Getting the wind knocked out of you** is the colloquial expression for a spasm in your diaphragm, usually caused by a blow to the abdomen. It may feel like one cannot inhale, thus giving rise to the expression.